# How to import Carbon/HIToolbox into objective c program?

Tags: macos-carbon

I'm new to Objective-C and I'm trying to use methods from [TextInputSources](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/Reference/reference.html) so I tried

`#import <Carbon/HIToolbox>`

and

`#import <HIToolbox/TextInputSources.h>`

nothing of those works. Is there something I'm missing? I'm using Xcode 3.

Comment: Why I m getting a down vote?!!!!

Comment: No idea, but I got one, too. Maybe somebody just hates Carbon?

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but I am curious why you would need these Carbon APIs in a Cocoa program.

Comment: Is there a cocoa alternative?.Just I read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781777/cocoa-learn-currently-selected-keyboard-layout-input-language and they are using carbon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56925840/why-does-import-hitoolbox-events-h-fail answers this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
```

It's a big header, but it always works.

You should probably do this in your prefix header, simply because including it anywhere else is going to slow down builds by a lot.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. It feels very clumsy to include this huge header just so that I can access (say) `kVK_Space`, which is in `HIToolbox/Events.h`.